# Unity Launcher is hard to access with auto-hide enabled

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit on my Acer netbook.

When I use AutoHide it is hard to get the Launcher to pop up, even with the sensitivity turned all the way up!  It seems the "sensitivity" has to do with how fast the mouse moves to the left (I have Launcher on the left), and I almost have to SLAM it over to expose the Launcher.

On this small screen, I want all the space to show, otherwise I can't even have my windows maximized without losing significant real-estate.

Is this feature working properly? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Related (analogous) question: [How can I change the “reveal pressure” to show Ubuntu Dock when it's (auto-) hidden?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1250029/480481)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing the Launcher Reveal Pressure.  The default is 20.  You might consider setting it at 1 and systematically try other settings to pick the ideal one.

You can get to this configuration through CCSM (the CompizConfig Settings Manager).

Click on Desktop -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> Launcher and change the '*Launcher Reveal Pressure*'.

You may have to install it.  This can be done by:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Comment: Sorry, new to this, had to actually READ the directions to figure out to check the box!  ALSO, this answer steered me to the CompizConfig install and manager, which was helpful with some other problems!

Comment: It seems the math involved in getting this to work is broken. Setting it to 1 is all that works.