# How can I change the "reveal pressure" to show Ubuntu Dock when it's (auto-) hidden?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, autohide

Previously, on older Ubuntu releases with Unity I could manually set the "*Launcher Reveal Pressure*" to increase or decrease the sensitivity to unhide the Unity Launcher when it's hidden using the *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/596532/480481)).

How can I do the same with Ubuntu Dock on newer Ubuntu releases with GNOME 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the "*require pressure to unhide the dock*" feature needs to be activated if it's not already. To do that, launch Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock require-pressure-to-show true
```

Then run the following command to set the pressure sensitivity

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock pressure-threshold <YOUR-VALUE>
```

In place of `<YOUR-VALUE>` use a numerical value of your choice, keeping in the mind that the default value is `100`.